# Error: Unsuccessful login with external provider using Federated Authentication

Tags: federated-authentication

We are trying to implement federated authentication using Google, but getting `Error: Unsuccessful login with external provider`. we had found few blogs to resolve this error which suggest to add name identifier claim, so we had added that one as well still we are getting same error. So can anyone please help us to identify what exactly we are missing?

We followed below steps:

1. Enabled `Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Enabler.config.example`
2. We had added required configuration in the same file as below

   ```
   <settings>
     <setting name="FederatedAuthentication.Enabled">
       <patch:attribute name="value">true</patch:attribute>
     </setting>
   </settings>

   <services>
     <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseAuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
               implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.AuthenticationManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
               lifetime="Singleton" />
     <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseTicketManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
               implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.TicketManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
               lifetime="Singleton" />
     <register serviceType="Sitecore.Abstractions.BasePreviewManager, Sitecore.Kernel"
               implementationType="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Publishing.PreviewManager, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication"
               lifetime="Singleton" />
   </services>

    <federatedAuthentication>
         <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
           <identityProvider id="Google" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.DefaultIdentityProvider, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
             <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
             <param desc="domainManager" type="Sitecore.Abstractions.BaseDomainManager" resolve="true" />
             <caption>Log in with Google</caption>
             <icon>/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/Images/24x24/Google.jpg</icon>
             <domain>sitecore</domain>
             <transformations hint="list:AddTransformation">
               <transformation name="set idp claim" ref="federatedAuthentication/sharedTransformations/setIdpClaim" />
               <transformation name="devRole" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultTransformation, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
                 <sources hint="raw:AddSource">
                   <claim name="idp" value="Google" />
                 </sources>
                 <targets hint="raw:AddTarget">
                   <claim name="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" value="Sitecore\Developer" />
                 </targets>
                 <keepSource>true</keepSource>
               </transformation>
             </transformations>
           </identityProvider>
         </identityProviders>
         <propertyInitializer type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.PropertyInitializer, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
           <maps hint="list">
             <map name="GoogleAdmin" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultClaimToPropertyMapper, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
               <data hint="raw:AddData">
                 <source name="idp" value="Google" />
                 <target name="IsAdministrator" value="true" />
               </data>
             </map>
           </maps>
         </propertyInitializer>
         <identityProvidersPerSites hint="list:AddIdentityProvidersPerSites">
           <mapEntry name="Google" type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Collections.IdentityProvidersPerSitesMapEntry, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
             <sites hint="list">
               <site>shell</site>
               <site>login</site>
               <site>admin</site>
               <site>service</site>
               <site>modules_shell</site>
               <site>modules_website</site>
               <site>website</site>
               <site>scheduler</site>
               <site>system</site>
               <site>publisher</site>
             </sites>
             <identityProviders hint="list:AddIdentityProvider">
               <identityProvider ref="federatedAuthentication/identityProviders/identityProvider[@id='Google']" />
             </identityProviders>
             <externalUserBuilder type="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Services.DefaultExternalUserBuilder, Sitecore.Owin.Authentication">
               <param desc="isPersistentUser">true</param>
             </externalUserBuilder>
           </mapEntry>
         </identityProvidersPerSites>
       </federatedAuthentication>
   ```
3. We created Google App for client id and api key
4. We created custom processor as below

   ```
   public class GoogleAuthentication : IdentityProvidersProcessor
   {
       public GoogleAuthentication(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration federatedAuthenticationConfiguration) : base(federatedAuthenticationConfiguration)
       {

       }

       protected override string IdentityProviderName
       {
           get { return "Google"; }
       }

       protected override void ProcessCore(IdentityProvidersArgs args)
       {
           Assert.ArgumentNotNull(args, "args");
           Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Configuration.IdentityProvider identityProvider = this.GetIdentityProvider();
           string authenticationType = this.GetAuthenticationType();


           var googleProvider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()
           {
               OnAuthenticated = (context) =>
               {
                   // transform all claims
                   ClaimsIdentity identity = context.Identity;
                   foreach (Transformation current in identityProvider.Transformations)
                   {
                       current.Transform(identity, new TransformationContext(FederatedAuthenticationConfiguration, identityProvider));
                   }
                   return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
               },

               OnReturnEndpoint = (context) =>
               {
                   if (context.Request.Query["state"] != null)
                   {
                       var state = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(context.Request.Query["state"]);

                   }

                   return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0);
               }
           };

           GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions googleOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions();
           googleOptions.ClientId = "***************************";
           googleOptions.ClientSecret = "***********************";
           googleOptions.Provider = googleProvider;
           googleOptions.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-google");

           args.App.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions);
       }
   }
   ```
5. We integrated custom possessor with owin pipeline as below

Can anyone please help us to identify what we missed in configuration or in code?

Comment: Can you try removing callbackpath and setting AuthenticationType = IdentityProvider.Name instead.

Comment: @josedbaez I tried your suggested change but still facing same issue, I had now implemented same thing with Facebook identity provides , same code only provider is different , for facebook its working fine, but for google after this url "https://accounts.google.co.in/accounts/SetSID" its redirect to sitecore application and throwing exception.

Comment: I did this one a while ago: https://github.com/josedbaez/sitecore9sso/blob/master/Pipelines/IdentityProviders/GoogleIdentityProvider.cs . Can't spot any major difference but maybe you can

Comment: Facing the exact same issue.. does any one has found solution to this issue.